# Unable to publish new channel entry

Tags: ee2, channel-entries

I'm trying to publish a new entry into an existing channel. This channel has one other entry. When I hit the Submit button on the new entry, I'm not seeing any error messages.

This same site has a dev instance, with its own database. I'm able to publish the entry on the dev site, but not on production. EDIT: I can add and edit templates on production, but cannot add or edit any channel entries. So possibly it's some channel setting???

How can I start troubleshooting this?

- Running ExpressionEngine 2.5.3, running on AWS
- Logged in as a super admin
- When I try to create or edit an entry, I just get taken right back to the entry form when I hit Submit
- Have tried turning on template debugging, but no change/no error messages generated

Comment: Are you logged in as Super Admin or a member in some other member group? In your main index.php page in site root also change $debug = 0; to $debug = 1;.

Comment: What happens when you hit submit? You say you're not seeing any error messages, but what *are* you seeing?

Comment: I've edited my question to include this info: I'm logged in as a Super Admin. When I hit Submit, I get taken right back to the entry edit form. (The site is otherwise displaying just fine.)

Comment: Be sure to check all of the publish form tabs for errors, sometimes they are hidden.

Comment: I'd had this before and it was a required field which had not been filled in. The error was subtle but it was causing the problem. Check any fields for any error messages too. Also do you have any addons installed such as QuickSave which interact with the publish page saving mechanism? One last thing to check is if you have the Pages module installed and is this a Page entry?

Comment: I also had a problem making minor edits to previous entries. I couldn't save them either. Literally, something as small as adding a period at the end of a sentence - couldn't save the entries. It's very frustrating!

Comment: So no QuickSave or similar addons installed? Is this a `Page` using the Pages Module or a channel entry?

Comment: This is a regular channel entry. (And nope, no QuickSave installed. We do have entry versioning enabled, but that's been that way for a while now.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a required field that isn't getting filled out on one of your publish tabs. Unfortunately, EE does a terrible job of indicating this error.

I suggest installing the [**EP Mega Error**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ep-mega-error) addon so you will always see such errors. Once installed, you will see a very obvious error like this:

[image]

Comment: Nope - that wasn't it. I went and made all channel fields NOT required, just in case. I even looked for the little error bar. (Thanks for telling me about EP Mega Error, though, I can think of other instances where something like this will be helpful. EE 2.x's CP has a few areas where usability is less than optimal, and error indication is one...)

Comment: Okay, next thing I'd suggest is to temporarily disable extensions by adding $config['allow_extensions'] = 'n'; to your config.php file. An extension could be causing a conflict.

Comment: Also, check the console in your browser... do you see any JS errors? If so, it's possible some JS for EE or an addon is missing, out of date or corrupted. Reuploading the file should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, simply refreshing the page first, then republishing may solve your issue. I have run into this a few times myself, and this has worked... I know it sounds rudimentary but try it.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that! I even tried loading it in each of the browsers I have installed on my laptop, just to make sure it wasn't some weird browser-specific issue that would have started happening since Monday.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. It's very weird.

This morning, I had opened the Admin>General Configuration settings screen, and set the site's root directory URL to be simply "/" so that people could view the site, or more specifically a certain set of templates, through either http or https. I've done this on other installs, even other installs for this particular client, and not had any problems.

Once I re-set the site's URL to the actual domain, instead of the more global "/", I could edit existing and publish new entries again.

Weird. Weird, weird, weird.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot here, but you're not seeing the published entry on the dev site, are you? Could it be using the dev database?

Comment: Nope, the entry is not showing up on either the dev nor the production database. (And nope, the dev and prod sites each use their own separate databases.)