# Client Not able to Add or Edit Entry

Tags: ee2, members, structure

I have a client that has been posting things to different channels for a while now.

Today They edited a page and that page all the sudden was not available. I went in as super admin and checked the status, entry date, and Hide From Nav (Using Structure). All were set correctly. I even Edited all those fields to the wrong setting saved and set them all back and the entry still did not show up.

I recreated the entry as Super Admin and the entry worked fine.

After the client added an entry and the same thing had happened. When I went in and manually duplicated the entry it worked fine.

Any ideas?
From Twitter I am about to check on Caching and testing if it is specific to that member or member group. If I find anything I will update.

Comment: See this post if it helps:
http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/content-entries-not-being-saved/11886#11886 Also can you update and add your versions - include Structure module. You don't have Publisher or Better Workflow installed I assume? Any other add-ons that may be relevant?

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd bug that typically happens when the channel isn't assigned to a status group. So, check that.

ADMIN > CHANNEL ADMINISTRATION > CHANNELS > "Edit Group Assignments" for your channel > assign status group